# Get IBM Cloud instances prices programmatically using IBM Global Catalog API

Tags: api, ibm-cloud

I am using [IBM Global Catalog API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/resource-catalog/global-catalog?code=java#get-pricing) to retrieve pricing info for IBM Cloud services. Looking at the API response , I cannot see any pricing info. for example , for cloud instance "bx2d-16x64", I am using the following link. Following link has all info about the instance "bx2d-16x64" but no pricing info. Could anyone please help here.

https://globalcatalog.cloud.ibm.com/api/v1/bx2d-16x64

Answer (score 1):

You might need to look under `Virtual Server for VPC` instead:
https://globalcatalog.cloud.ibm.com/update/is.instance?noLocations=true

From there, you can pick the instance type on the left `Standard Gen 2` as example:
https://globalcatalog.cloud.ibm.com/update/a736a57f-0584-474f-8411-55dc7d9dc811?noLocations=true

Then pick the `us-south` deployment:
https://globalcatalog.cloud.ibm.com/update/a736a57f-0584-474f-8411-55dc7d9dc811:us-south18268?noLocations=true

Finally in pricing:
https://globalcatalog.cloud.ibm.com/update/a736a57f-0584-474f-8411-55dc7d9dc811:us-south18268?noLocations=true&tab=pricing

Based on this, here is what I'm finding:

- For memory

  - charge unit is MEMORY_HOURS
  - charge unit quantity is 450
  - USD price is 2.033
- For vCPU (assuming CentOS)

  - charge unit is VCPU_HOURS
  - charge unit quantity is 63
  - USD price is 1.7869
- For instance storage

  - charge unit is IS_STORAGE_GIGABYTE_HOURS
  - charge unit quantity is 1
  - USD price is 0.00011726130000000001

Comment: Many thanks for helping me out, I have got a better idea now. https://globalcatalog.cloud.ibm.com/update/virtual-server-group?noLocations=true    Using this link, I donot see any prices here. Could you please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: https://cloud.ibm.com/gen1/infrastructure/provision/vs  Here is the link which should be pulling prices from the Global Catalog API https://globalcatalog.cloud.ibm.com/update/virtual-server-group?noLocations=true

Comment: I wonder if for the Gen1 VSI you may need to use this API https://sldn.softlayer.com/, https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price/